# MongoDB indexing not working (1 million records)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

**Configuration of remote server:**
Ubuntu 20.04 on Digital ocean (1vcpu, 1GM Ram, 25GB memory)
MongoDb running on Digital ocean machine

**Local machine:**
MacOS, Dockerized Nodejs express server (from here I am searching through my collections)

I created 2 collections in my DB, one is indexed (PartnerModelIndex) and another not (PartnerModel).

- *See picture:*

[image]

I created 2 API routes on my NodeJS - only one of them searches through indexed collection:

[image]

I also filled my collections with 1.000.000 (million) documents with following parameters:

- **title** - has approximately 20-30 words (each document)
- **description** - has approximately 5k - 6k characters (each document)

[image]

Here is my MongoDB compass showing the occupied memory by indexes:

**The problem is that when I try to search for any non-existent string in my database (through title and description) I get the same execution time for both indexed and non-indexed collection, *see image***

[image]

**And non-indexed:**

[image]

What could be the reason for this strange behavior?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3027266

Answer (score 0):

When evaluating the clauses in the $or expression, MongoDB either performs a collection scan or, if all the clauses are supported by indexes, MongoDB performs index scans. That is, for MongoDB to use indexes to evaluate an $or expression, all the clauses in the $or expression must be supported by indexes. Otherwise, MongoDB will perform a collection scan.

Ref: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/why-is-mongodb-not-taking-an-existing-unique-compound-index-for-an-or-query/103229